# Как работает sync?

Tags: c++

Не могу понять как он работает. Есть пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
void file_abc()
{
    std::ofstream f("test.txt");
    f << "abc\n";
}
void file_123()
{
    std::ofstream f("test.txt");
    f << "123\n";
}
int main()
{
    file_abc(); // file now contains "abc"
    std::ifstream f("test.txt");
    std::cout << "Reading from the file\n";
    char c;
    f >> c; std::cout << c;
    file_123(); // file now contains "123"
    f >> c; std::cout << c;
    f >> c; std::cout << c << '\n';
    f.close();

    file_abc(); // file now contains "abc"
    f.open("test.txt");
    std::cout << "Reading from the file, with sync()\n";
    f >> c; std::cout << c;
    file_123(); // file now contains "123"
    std::cout << f.sync() << std::endl;
    f >> c; std::cout << c;
    f >> c; std::cout << c << '\n';
}
```

и вывод должен быть вроде как :

```
Reading from the file
abc
Reading from the file, with sync()
a23
```

Но у меня получается

```
Reading from the file
abc
Reading from the file
abc
```

При этом f.sync() выдает 0. Как все таки это работает?

Comment: скомилил, явно выводит  `with sync()`. Пересоберите проект.

Comment: @KoVadim прошу прощение не понял что значит скомилил и with sync()?

Comment: эм... скопировал код, скопировал в файл, запустил g++ имя-файла, потом запустил ./a.out. Вывело то, что Вы ожидаете.

Comment: @KoVadim да я в курсе, что на некоторых системах оно выводит то, что ожидается, но не понимаю почему. У вас что выводит f.sync()? 0?

Comment: f.sync() выводит ноль

Comment: @KoVadim вот и у меня, а вывод почему то другой. И на сайте cppreference.com, откуда взят этот пример, говорится, что этот вывод будет на "некоторых платформах". По крайней мере на сколько я знаю английский.

Comment: Если у Вас не выводится надпись "Reading from the file, with sync()", то значит, что либо не тот бинарь компилируете, либо  оно падает,  либо я чего то не знаю о стандартной библиотеке

Comment: @KoVadim по видимому последнее, так как бинарь точно тот, надпись не выводится, а значение cin.sync() равно 0.

Comment: Я тоже попробовал в `g++.real (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609; Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS \n \l; x86_64 GNU/Linux` и получил после `Reading from the file, with sync()` вывод `a0` и с новой строки `bc`. Т.е. `f.sync` возвращает 0, но буфер не синхронизируется с новым содержимым файла (да, я вставил чтение cin сразу после вызова `file_123();` и убедился, что `cat test.txt` выводит `123`. Запись в файл другого количества символов также на результат не влияет). *Выводы делайте сами*

Comment: Дополнительно я посмотрел на вывод `strace ./a.out` с вашей программой и не увидел никаких системных вызовов с помощью которых `f.sync()` могла бы заметить изменения в файле. Т.е. **в моей реализации крестов данная функция просто пустышка**

Comment: И еще -- у вас заголовок вопроса о **cin.sync()**, а текст о **f.sync** (и stream *f* точно не *cin*). Поправьте

Comment: @avp ок, исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере параллельного чтения и записи в один файл функция **sync** не спасёт, так как операционка не будет блокировать и синхронизировать бесконечный поток открытия файлов. После открытия файла на чтение все клиенты будут читать одно и то-же из буфера. При изменении файла следующие клиенты будут читать файл из буфера второго и тоже удивляться, что бабка Рая говорила другое. 
Результат чтения исходников и переводов. Функция **sync** обновляет буфер чтения до упора памяти. Если буфер заполнен полностью и ничего не добавилось всё остаётся точно так-же. Если файл изменился, то заново буфер обновлятся не будет. Если у вас было желание обновить содержимое буфера, то этот буфер нужно обнулить. Это можно достичь с помощью `f.seekg(f.tellg());`. Более красивого способа не нашёл.

Comment: Но почему на одних операционках оно работает как в примере, а в других - нет? И в чем смысл этой функции?

Comment: В инструкции C++ пытался разжевать английский , там в примерах только **cin** и объясняли, что кэш операционки собственный сливает клиентской программе до упора. Можно поигратся с обновлением файла в режиме **append** и посмотреть результат.

Comment: Почитал файл заново без закрытия с помощью `f.seekg(0);` получил одинаково новые цифры что с **sync** что без. Инструкцию на русском надо раскопать по **sync**.

Comment: Если у вас было желание обновить содержимое буфера, то этот буфер нужно обнулить. Это можно достичь с помощью `f.seekg(f.tellg());`. Более красивого способа не нашёл.

Comment: нет, подобного желания у меня не было) просто увидел эту функцию в коде и заинтересовался зачем она нужна. В том коде автор использовал ее неправильно: для обнуления буфера, из-зс чего у меня возникли проблемы на линуксе при выполнении проги. Хотел узнать что она вообще должна выполнять по стандарту - ну а дальше вы знаете)

Comment: Везде **sync** юзают кажется только в однонаправленных потоках, где главная задача - поймать свежак. В файлах кажется такая запара никому не нужна.